# Android 3.0 Emulator has Bluetooth included?

Tags: android-emulator, bluetooth, android-3.0-honeycomb

I know that there is no Bluetooth support for Android Emulator 2.0. What about 3.0 (Honeycomb)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, I don't think that the 3.0 Android Emulator have open support for BT